# Updating SQL Server database through C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-update

I am having trouble on what I should implement for updating and SQL Server through C#.

The situation is that a user might want to update a product in the system and if no image is selected the fields that hold the image paths are all NULL.

I put in a check to see if the fileupload control has a file to upload it but if the control doesn't have a file then it should run an update query to update the remaining fields and not the field that's tied to the fileupload control.

Below is the code behind for the page.

```
protected void FormView1_ItemUpdating(object sender, FormViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{ 
  FileUpload FileUpload1 = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload3");
  FileUpload FileUpload2 = (FileUpload)FormView1.FindControl("FileUpload4");


  if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
  {
      string virtualFolder1 = "~/ProductArt/Thumb/";
      string physicalFolder1 = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder1);
      string oldkey = e.Keys["ItemID"].ToString();
      //string photopath1 = e.OldValues["ThumbPath"].ToString();
      string ext1 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder1, oldkey + ext1));
      //e.Values["ThumbPath"] = photopath1 + ext1;
      e.NewValues["ThumbPath"] = virtualFolder1 + oldkey + ext1;
  }
  else
  {
      //throw new Exception("Error, no thumb file selected");
      SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("TTEConnectionString");
      connect.Open();
      SqlCommand cmdQuery = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE Item SET ItemName='" + txtItemNameTextBox.Text + "', PublisherID='" + ddlPublisher.SelectedValue );
  }

  if (FileUpload2.HasFile)
  {
      string virtualFolder2 = "~/ProductArt/";
      string physicalFolder2 = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder2);
      string oldkey2 = e.Keys["ItemID"].ToString();
      //string photopath1 = e.OldValues["ThumbPath"].ToString();
      string ext2 = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload2.FileName);
      FileUpload2.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder2, oldkey2 + ext2));
      //e.Values["ThumbPath"] = photopath1 + ext1;
      e.NewValues["PhotoPath"] = virtualFolder2 + oldkey2 + ext2;
  }
  else
  {
      throw new Exception("Error, no full box file selected");
  }
}
```

Also, whenever I type in an ID of an ASP text box it would give the

> the name xxxx does not exist in the current context

error.

Comment: `UPDATE` without a `WHERE` clause hmmm

Comment: well I was trying to build the query though I keep getting the 'the name doesn't exist in the current context' error.

I must be missing something.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

You're missing Where clause in your update query.

You need to pass null value for the field that you don't have value. i.e Fileupload filed in db.

You can have query like below which will update the record with existing value if it is null (as passed from frontend)

```
Update yourtable
set fileuploadfiled=isnull(@fileuploadfield,fileuploadfield),
--Remaining fileds to be updated
where id=@id
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: i know that but when i try and link the columns to the values in the ASPX page it gives the 'the name doesn't exist in the current context'.

Comment: Make sure your textbox is having the same name as in your code and have runat="server"